# Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения

Tags: sql, sql-server

Мне надо вывести всех сотрудников по иерерхии на xml( структуру компании). Но у меня возникает проблема. В моей базе 3 таблицы:  1 структура компании: hid, level, name(наименование дотлела)2 сотрудники:id, fio, email, active. 3 связь между ними: id, structureid(=hid), recipient(Id сотрудника). И ещё у меня есть представления. Там представлена сотрудники в соответствующим отделе. Вот запрос:

```
Select 
S.hid as "@hid",
S.[level] as "@level",
S.name as "@name",
(Select name from [dbo].[V_ACS_aa] r  where s.hid=r.hid) as ' staff ', ( 
/*ошибка у меня здесь , если у меня сотрудник один у меня все нормально, 
но если у меня сотрудников больше одного,
    то тогда вложенный зарос больше одного значения, 
    так как у меня много сотрудников равные одному hid*/
)
    Case when  @hid =s.hid.GetAncestor(1) then [dbo].[Akzhol](s.hid' limit  - 1) end 
    From  [dbo].[onec_companystructure] s 
    Where @hid=s.hid.GetAncestor(1) 
    For xml path('path'), type 
    )
    End
    );
End
```

Comment: а не проще ли это в коде сделать? в sql выбираете сотрудников, заполняете для них информацию, а в коде уже группируете по отделам и прочему (т.е. создаете структуру компании), и только потом делаете экспорт данных

Comment: @Asd Вы определитесь что хотите получить в случае когда у вас больше одного сотрудника - если несколько записей, то выносите свой подзапрос во from, вернее только траблицу и просто join'ите ее. Если записб должна остаться только одна - то решите имя какого сотрудника хотите показать, может там стоит применить функци min/max ...

Answer (score 3):

> Запрос вернул больше одного значения.

Такая ошибка возникает, когда вы вставляете подзапрос в место, где от него требуется скалярное значение (одна строка с одним столбцом), но при этом запрос возвращает не 1 строку, а больше. Сервер логичным образом не может выбрать какую строку из множества использовать.
Вы сначала для себя должны решить как именно надо обрабатывать ситуацию с несколькими значениями в подзапросе.

Тут может быть 3 варианта:

1) Вам нужно любое значение из списка. Тогда просто дописываем к нашему запросу ТОП-1.

2) Вам нужно значение агрегатной функции от списка. Т.е. минимальное значение или максимальное или сумма и.т.д. В этом случае дорисовываем соответствующую функцию.

3) Вас интересуют ВСЕ значения из списка, но получить их надо в одной строке. Склеиваем все значения в нужном порядке в подзапросе в одну строку(тем же FOR XML PATH, например).

Comment: Можно по подробнее. У меня например в таблице есть столбец name и hid(hierarchy) мне надо вывести всех сотрудников соответствующим отделе . У меня в одном отделе несколько сотрудников и конечно у соотрудников одинаковый hid. Если  в одном депортаменте один сотрудник , тогда у меня все выводится.

Comment: А если два или более сотрудников? Как вы хотите их вывести? см. про 3 варианта в ответе.

А лучше приведите пример запроса, который работает(т.е. у вас не работает, когда сотрудников больше одного). Желательно с созданием таблиц и данными.

Comment: Ещё раз попрошу. Приведите в тексте вопроса корректный пример кода, который у вас не работает, когда сотрудников больше одного.

Comment: У меня все сработало. Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, вы пытаетесь вложить элементы, но делаете это образом для этого неподходящим.

Вот вам для примера два запроса, которые возвращают одно и то же. В обоих я закомментировал второго сотрудника.

Первый:

```
select
    'Level Name' as '@name',
    1 as '@level',
    (
        select Name
        from (values
            ('Staff Name')
            --,('Staff Name2')
            ) staff(Name)
    ) 'staff'
for xml path('level')
```

Второй:

```
select
    'Level Name' as '@name',
    1 as '@level',
    (
        select Name as 'text()'
        from (values
            ('Staff Name')
            --,('Staff Name2')
            ) staff(Name)
        for xml path('staff'), type
    )
for xml path('level')
```

Если его разкомментировать, первый выдаст ошибку, второй - нет.